# How to write metadata from scratch for a point fc stored in a GDB?

Tags: metadata, fme-transformer

I have a point feature class in a geodatabase. It doesn't contain metadata yet. I want to write one for it. I think I need to use XML Templater. But I can't read directly from GDB by adding a Esri GDB reader. what should my source be?